# What is the proper hreflang setup for translated pages?

Tags: seo, internationalization, translation

We are trying to figure what is the correct `hreflang` attributes that should be displayed on our pages. We have 4 languages that we will enable for all our pages: `English`, `French`, `Spanish`, `German`. Our site is setup as below.

- All `English` pages will be accessible through `https://www.example.com/some-path`
- All `French` pages will be accessible through `https://fr.example.com/some-path`
- All `Spanish` pages will be accessible through `https://es.example.com/some-path`
- All `German` pages will be accessible through `https://de.example.com/some-path`

**What is the correct format to display the `hreflang` attributes so that it is crawled correctly by search engines without taking a hit for SEO?**

Here is what we tried.

Option 1

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="example.com/some-path">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-es" href="example.com/some-path">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-fr" href="example.com/some-path">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-ca" href="example.com/some-path">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-de" href="example.com/some-path">
```

Option 2

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="https://www.example.com/some-path">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-es" href="https://es.example.com/some-path">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-fr" href="https://fr.example.com/some-path">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-ca" href="https://fr.example.com/some-path">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-de" href="https://de.example.com/some-path">
```

Option 3

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="www.example.com/some-path">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-es" href="www.example.com/es-es/some-path">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-fr" href="www.example.com/fr-fr/some-path">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-ca" href="www.example.com/fr-ca/some-path">
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-de" href="www.example.com/de-de/some-path">
```

The goal we are trying to achieve is we want to follow the [Supported language/region codes](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) section from webmasters. At some point we will enable more languages such as `French for Belgium` and `French for Canada`

> Do not specify a country code by itself. Google does not automatically
>   derive the language from the country code. You can specify a language
>   code by itself if you want to simplify your labeling.  Adding the
>   country code after the language to restrict the page to a specific
>   region.  Examples:
>
> be: Belarusian language, independent of region (not Belgium French)
>
> nl-be: Dutch for Belgium
>
> fr-be: French for Belgium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hreflang tag needs to be a fully qualified URL including a protocol part of some sort.

Take a properly formatted language tag like this one as an example:

```
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="es-es" href="https://es.example.com/some-path">
```

Crawlers read that tag literally like this:

> There is an alternate version of this page available in the Spanish ([ISO 639-1 code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes) `es`) language targeted towards residents of Spain ([ISO 3166-1 Alpha 2 country code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2) `-es`) at the URL `https://es.example.com/some-path`.

Using the `alternate` tag, you are literally telling the crawler the URL where this page's foreign-language counterpart is located. If you copy the URL from the `href` attribute of the tag and paste it into a fresh browser session, the foreign language page should load in your browser. That's one of the ways to know you have it set up properly.

Comment: the main reason for having `fr-fr` is that we wanted to indicate it was `French for France`. At some point in `phase 2` of our translation project, we will want to deploy `French for Canada` and `French for Belgium`.

Comment: I think the list I found of valid language codes may be wrong. I'm looking into it more.

Comment: I believe you may be looking for [ISO Language Code Table](http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm). In general, the first part is required, also called `lang_code`, but the second part is optional. For example for `fr-CA`, `fr` would be `lang_code` and `CA` would be country/region.

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm sitting here scratching my head, as the first two resources I found were incomplete and misleading. You're totally right, from what I can tell, it's all well and good to target the main region of a language using an *ISO 3166-1 Alpha 2* region code.

Comment: In fact, the RFC [uses `de-DE` as an example of a valid language code](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5646#page-80).

Comment: Sounds like `option 2` from my question. Your answer is very similar to that. I have additionally updated my question to include the `fr-ca` so it is more clear.

Comment: @usernameabc Yep. Option 2, since you have edited it, is the same as my recommendation now.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are making this too difficult(?). Start the pages with the typical declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
```

or, `"fr-fr"`, or `"es"`, etc. Goole, other search engines, and browsers will not have any question about what language to display.

Comment: still need to display the correct `hreflang` attribute or are you saying that having `lang=en`, `lang=fr-fr`, and other languages negates the importance of `hreflang`?

Comment: It seems to me that they do much the same thing (i.e.; provide information to search engines and servers as to which language is contained on the page.) reference: [Mozilla hreflang attribute](https://moz.com/learn/seo/hreflang-tag), [W3C Declaring language in HMTL](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations)